# What is the ideal temperature/cooldown time for coffee brewed in a Keurig K-mini?

Tags: temperature, keurig

There are no temperature settings on the Keurig K-mini, only ounches to brew. What is the best wait time for the freshly-brewed coffee to cool down before consuption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, it's whatever you prefer. Of course you don't want to drink it so hot that you scald your mouth, so the high end is generally in the range of any other beverage that you drink hot.

But your perception of the flavors is affected by the temperature. If you've ever participated in a coffee tasting, you focus not only on the flavor profile, but how it changes as the coffee cools down. While it's still very hot, you perceive less of the flavor in general. As the temperature drops into a range where your taste buds work well, you'll perceive more full and nuanced flavor, and notice a change in the flavor profile as it gets cooler.

If you order coffee from a coffee shop, they don't wait until the temperature is at some optimum before giving it to you. If you don't chug it down but drink it over time as it cools, you'll get to experience a range of flavors. Depending on your coffee preferences, you can choose to experience the full range of flavors, or find a temperature you like best and drink it all close to that point.

That applies no matter how you brew it (assuming it's hot).